# my border bottom edge is cut off

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with border bottom. The left and right edge are somehow cut and they do not touch each other

```
<nav>
    <ul class="cd-tabs-navigation">
        <li class="col-xs-2 no-padding"><a data-content="passenger" class="selected" href="#0">></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-2 no-padding"><a data-content="truck" href="#0"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-2 no-padding"><a data-content="machine" href="#0"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- cd-tabs-navigation -->
</nav>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ve4qfq45/2/)

Comment: Check with developer tool(like firebug) you will find your issue easily.

Comment: I try with firebug before asking this question, and cant find why it cuts. Mayby i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `a` element being only 143px high (with border) while the others are 146px.
You can fix this by adding `height: 143px` (so with border it'll be 146px) to `.cd-tabs-navigation a.selected`:

```
.cd-tabs-navigation a.selected
{
    color: #29324e;
    border: 3px solid #fcb320;
    padding: 0px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 143px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ve4qfq45/3/).

Comment: Thanks, i just comment this: /*  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
      border-right: 3px solid transparent;*/ and its ok